# Does "carné de conducir" involve meat?

Tags: etimología

I'm an English developer working on some multilingual software, and I'm just loading in some translations for Spanish (which I *believe* have been translated by an actual Spanish person).

One of the terms is ***driving licence***. This has come back as **carné de conducir**.

My extremely limited knowledge of Spanish leads me to believe **carné** refers to meat (as in, animal flesh...).

Obviously, a literal translation isn't always useful, but I'm now intrigued. What is the background of this?

Comment: To complement the good answer you already received, I would like to emphasize that besides having different etymology, "carne" and "carné" don't sound similar to a native speaker. Probably the same way you (likely, I guess) don't consider "desert" and "dessert" similar words. Or "ice" and "eyes", which are a nightmare for me as a non-native English speaker.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

*[Carné](https://dle.rae.es/carn%C3%A9#3KAsYxe)* (note the accent on the *e*), also spelt *[carnet](https://dle.rae.es/carnet?m=form)*, comes from French *carnet* which means "booklet" or "notebook". The Spanish word *carné* is also used to refer to an ID card, a membership card, or a card that gives its owner some permission or license (such as a driving license).

It has nothing to do with *[carne](https://dle.rae.es/carne?m=form)* (without accent on the *e*) which comes from Latin and means "flesh" or "meat".

Note that the two words are pronounced differently: *carné* is pronounced with stress on the second syllable, while *carne* has the stress on the first syllable.

Comment: In at least some countries the standard spelling is in fact “carnet” (Venezuela). I had never seen it spelled without the “t”.

Comment: In fact the DLE does define _carnet_ as a synonym but without any suggestion of it being a regional variation @EuroMicelli

Comment: @EuroMicelli yes, also in Spain the spelling *carnet* is sometimes used. I added this option to the answer.